# TypeError: req.next is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Getting this error in node, I think it's due to something to do with one of my pieces of middleware, but the line of code that it points to is my user controller at a res.render() call.

I can't find anyone writing about this error online and couldn't figure out the cause after looking at the code for a while. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: `next` is independent function, it's not a part of `req` object. Do you call `req.next` in your code?

Comment: No, I don't  ..

Comment: What do you call on 79th line of `users.js` module?

Comment: Just a res.render(), though I'm pretty sure it throws on multiple routes

Comment: You use `express-flash`. Are you sure that you configured it properly?

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the Express source code you'll see that line 966 of `response.js` (from the stack) is this:

```
if (err) return req.next(err);
```

The error message you're seeing suggests that `req` is defined but `next` is not a function. If you look a bit further up you can see where `req` is coming from:

```
var req = this.req;
```

where `this` is the response object that you called `render` on.

While `next` is usually just passed as an argument to a callback, there is also supposed to be a function called `next` attached to the request. It isn't something you'd normally interact with yourself, it's part of the inner workings.

So I see two possibilities. Either something has changed `res.req` to point at the wrong object, or something has blown away `req.next`. I suggest adding in some console logging to isolate exactly where this goes wrong. For example, if you put this between each of your middleware calls:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(typeof req.next);

    next();
});
```

it'll allow you to identify the point where `req.next` switches from being the function it should be to being something else.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the really thorough answer, I'll have a chance to look at this soon and get back to you but I think this will work for helping me get this debugged.

Comment: I found the bug, I was calling next() twice within the same middleware.

Comment: @Antoine I had made the same exact mistake.

Comment: I have this same issue, but no idea which next() is triggering it as the error doesn't say which file caused it, so it could be anywhere in my app...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I need to **return** the **next()**

```
// Error
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if(!req.session.userId) {
        next(); // <<<<< Error
      } 
    })

// Solution
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if(!req.session.userId) {
        return next();
      } 
    })
```

Comment: Returning `next()` is a common pattern but not strictly required. The key thing is not calling `next()` twice. Returning will just stop subsequent code from running, so any other calls to `next()` in the same function won't be reached. The value returned is not important.