# Sending user data to pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I' ve created middleware function which is supposed to send user data to pug template and according to this data it should display different features on the site if user is logged in or not.

```
exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.cookies.jwt) {
    try {
      //1) Verify token
      console.log(typeof req.next, "verify");
      const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
        req.cookies.jwt,
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
      );
      //console.log(decoded);
      //2) Check if user still exists
      db.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        //console.log(decoded.id, " id");
        const search_query = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [decoded.id]);
        connection.query(search_query, (err, result) => {
          connection.release();
          if (result == 0) {
            console.log(typeof req.next, "if");
            return next();
          }
          // THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER
          req.user = result.id;
          res.locals.user = result.id;
          console.log(typeof req.next, "locals");
          return next();
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(typeof req.next, "catch");
      return next();
    }
    // res.locals.user = req.user;
    // return next();
  }
  next();
};
```

Router

```
const express = require("express");
const viewsController = require("../controllers/viewsController");
const authController = require("../controllers/authController");

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', viewsController.getOverview);
router.get('/loginSignup', viewsController.getLoginSignup);
router.get("/subjects", viewsController.getSubjects);
router.get("/courses", authController.isLoggedIn, viewsController.getCourses);
router.get('/subjects/:slug', viewsController.loadSubject);

module.exports = router;
```

viewsController.getCourses function:

```
exports.getCourses = (req, res) => {
  db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    //console.log('in get courses');
    if (err) throw err;
    const sqlSearch = "Select * from courses";
    const search_query = mysql.format(sqlSearch);
    connection.query(search_query, (err, result) => {
      connection.release();
      if (result.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "There are no courses" });
      } else {
        res.status(200).render("courses", {
          title: "Courses we offer",
          courses: result,
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

part of the overview.pug file:

```
section.course
  a(href='/courses')
    h1 Courses we offer
  p
    | Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, quae
    | laboriosam? Beatae nesciunt, sunt, temporibus dignissimos obcaecati
    | voluptatum sed nobis ab saepe rem voluptatem! Quod animi sit unde
    | asperiores maiores!
  .row
    each _, i in Array(3) 
      .course-col
        h3= courses[i].name
        p= courses[i].summary
```

This is what I got in the terminal window:

```
GET / 304 86.750 ms - -
function verify
function locals
GET /courses 404 4.484 ms - 146
C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1034
    if (err) return req.next(err);
                        ^

TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1034:25)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:659:5)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at Query.onResult (C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\controllers\viewsController.js:85:25)
    at C:\Users\gotha\OneDrive\Pulpit\HTML_CSS_JS\uczelnia\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\query.js:86:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

I' ve tried to find some solutions to this problem but I can't solve it on my own. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: req.next is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203475/typeerror-req-next-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I've tried it and all console.logs show that req.next is a function and i return next().